# Check if DocumentFragment is a normal Node

Tags: javascript, dom, documentfragment

I've believed that my problem is pretty simple but after spending some time searching I cannot find a satisfactory solution.

I have a DocumentFragment element and I want to check if it's wrapped entirely by some html tag. Here is pseudo code which I'm trying to turn into JavaScript:

```
entireTagSelected = function (selRange) {
  var documentFragment = selRange.cloneContents();
  if (documentFragment is wrapped entirely by something) {
    return something;
  }
  return undefined;
}
```

For DocumentFragment like:

```
<span>Te<b>s</b>t</span>
```

the function should return span object.

But for fragments like:

```
Some text<span>Test</span>
```

it should return undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the children of the `documentFragment`, and if the `length` is 1 and  its `nodeType == 1` then it is a single element.

```js
function entireTagSelected (selRange) {
  var documentFragment = selRange.content
  var children = documentFragment.childNodes
  if ( children.length == 1 && children[0].nodeType == 1 ) 
    return children[0]
}


var template1 = document.createElement( 'template' )
template1.innerHTML = "<span>Te<b>s</b>t</span>"

var template2 = document.createElement( 'template' )
template2.innerHTML = "Some text<span>Test</span>"

var template3 = document.createElement( 'template' )
template3.innerHTML = "Only text"

console.log( entireTagSelected( template1 ) )
console.log( entireTagSelected( template2 ) )
console.log( entireTagSelected( template3 ) )
```